# SQL: Sorting the same column asc then desc

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I tried using order by clause to sort and re-sort the data on the same column. My query was:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Country ASC, Country DESC;
```

The result is surprising. It sorts the `Country` Column in Ascending Order only.

According to my knowledge, the `Country` Column should have been sorted in an Ascending order first, then in a Descending order.

Why did SQL skip the next part of the query?

Comment: It's first sorted by `Country ASC`, then *within that sort* the `Country DESC` sort is applied. Since you are using the same attribute, the 2nd sort doesn't do anything. The `ORDER BY` as posted naturally makes no sense at all, try the 2nd sort with customerid or something to see what is happening.

Comment: First sort by Country ASC, then sort the within duplicates by Country DESC...

Comment: @JacobH Obviously, I cannot sort it in an ascending as well as descending order. I just want a proper explanation as to why the second part of the clause did not work.

Comment: I'm really excited to know your expected result. First sort by country asc and then by country desc, last wins or what?

Comment: How are you even able to run this query? When I try something similar I get `Msg 169, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.`

Comment: @JacobH: The world of DBMS products is not limited to SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name really? please tell me more...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you specify multiple items in `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering is determined as follows:

- Results are sorted using the first order specification (column name + direction)
- Any ties that remain are resolved using the second order specification,
- Any ties that remain are resolved using the third order specification, and so on.

Resolving ties using the same column, regardless of the direction, wouldn't change the ordering, because the values in the column are the same within the tied group.